# hov create ms sql Trigger on many rows (like oracle FOR EACH ROW)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

In oracle i create triggers without problems, but in tsql i heave one big problem :)

I have a job, who insert rows into one tabel:

````
SELECT wa.IdAnkiety      
     ,wa.IdUsterkiService
      ,wa.LiczbaGlosowTak
       ,wa.LiczbaGlosowNie   FROM [SERV-SQL01].[DomTransfer].[dbo].[D5Cts_WynikiAnkiet] wa   where not
 exists (select wy.IdUsterkiService     from dba.DOM_WyAnkiet wy 
    where   wy.IdUsterkiService=wa.IdUsterkiService     and
 wy.IdAnkiety=wa.IdAnkiety)```

And on this: dba.DOM_WyAnkiet tble I heave a trigger
````

```
ALTER trigger [dba].[wyankiet]
on [dba].[DOM_WyAnkiet] AFTER insert
AS
begin

declare @DefectActId uniqueidentifier,
        @tak int,
        @nie int;

    select @DefectActId=IdUsterkiService, @tak=tak, @nie=nie from inserted;

    if @tak>@nie
        update dba.DefectAct set status='49A86504-2E7D-46AB-A022-FC4C3C8CA853', InspectionDate=GETDATE() where DefectActId=@DefectActId;

    if @nie>@tak
        update dba.DefectAct set status='2EDA9FB2-8ED2-43AC-8C30-348D3F060CE3',InspectionDate=GETDATE() where DefectActId=@DefectActId;

    if @nie=@tak
        update dba.DefectAct set status='588B5BAA-F7CE-455D-9489-B2B956949449',InspectionDate=GETDATE() where DefectActId=@DefectActId;

end
```

But seems thats nor works
in oracle i add the FOR EACH ROW command and something like here above are works.

Comment: `inserted` is the collection of rows that were inserted, so treat it like a table of rows instead of a single row.

Comment: Have a read of [Bad Habits to Kick : Abusing triggers](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-abusing-triggers). Your `TRIGGER` **assumes** that an `INSERT` only contains 1 row; which is simply not true. It seems odd, however, that you set `InspectionDate` to `GETDATE()` in the trigger; why not use a `DEFAULT` value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle a multi-row insert. join to the `inserted` virtual table instead of assigning scalar variables. Below is an example (untested) of this set-based technique using a `CASE` expression:

```
ALTER trigger [dba].[wyankiet]
    ON[dba].[DOM_WyAnkiet] AFTER INSERT
AS
UPDATE da
    set status=
        CASE 
            WHEN i.tak>i.nie THEN '49A86504-2E7D-46AB-A022-FC4C3C8CA853'
            WHEN i.nie>i.tak THEN '2EDA9FB2-8ED2-43AC-8C30-348D3F060CE3'
            WHEN i.nie=i.tak THEN '588B5BAA-F7CE-455D-9489-B2B956949449'
        END
    , InspectionDate=GETDATE()
FROM dba.DefectAct AS da
JOIN inserted AS i ON i.DefectActId=da.DefectActId;
```